# How to compute conditional density function in this particular case?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, density-function

> Suppose we have two random variables $\xi,\eta$, which are defined on the same probability space and $\xi \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$. Moreover, $\forall \lambda\in[0,1]:(\eta|\xi=\lambda)\sim \mathcal{Be}(\lambda)$.

I need to find the distribution of $\eta$. In order to do so, I need to calculate $f_{\xi}(\lambda|\eta=t)$, but how does one compute it? In the question [conditional probability combining discrete and continous random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332879/conditional-probability-combining-discrete-and-continous-random-variables) user Wio computes it using  *joint probability density*, but is it really possible, given that one of the variables is absolutely continuous and the other is discrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}P(\eta \leq t)&=E[P(\eta\leq t|\xi)]=\\
&=\int_0^1P(\eta\leq t|\xi=y)dy=\\
&=\int_0^1(y \mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq t<1\}}(t)+\mathbf{1}_{\{t\geq 1\}}(t))dy=\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq t<1\}}(t)+\mathbf{1}_{\{t\geq 1\}}(t)\end{aligned}$$
We may conclude $\eta \sim \textrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$.

Comment: Why $\mathbb{P}[\eta\leq t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}[\eta\leq t|\xi]]$? Is this some kind of generalization of the total probability formula?

Comment: @Egor [Total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation): $P(\eta \leq t)=E[\mathbf{1}_{\{\eta \leq t\}}]=E[E[\mathbf{1}_{\{\eta \leq t\}}|\xi]]=E[P(\eta\leq t|\xi)]$

Comment: So we didn't use the distribution of $\xi$ in this solution? It seems that the only relevant thing was $(\eta|\xi = \lambda)\sim \mathrm{Be}(\lambda)$...

Comment: Oh, it seems like we used it to argue that $dF_{\xi} = f_{\xi}dy = dy?$

Comment: @Egor, indeed, we took the expectation wrt to the law of $\xi$, which is just uniform over the unit interval.